# Creating kubernetes cluster inside an existing VPC in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

To create kubernetes cluster in AWS, I use the set up script "https://get.k8s.io". That script creates a new VPC automatically, but I want to create kubernetes cluster inside an existing VPC in AWS. Is there a way to do it?

I checked /kubernetes/cluster/aws/config-default.sh file, but there doesn't seem to be any environment variables about VPC.

Answer (score 7):

You can add this ENV variable (we are using ver 1.1.8)

`export VPC_ID=vpc-YOURID`

Also Kubernetes creates a VPC with 172.20.0.0/16 and I think it expects this.

Comment: While this will work to setup your cluster, be warned that `kube-down.sh` doesn't currently play nice with this and will not delete your cluster.

Comment: Is there a way to assign it an existing instance ID where it creates a cluster. I don't want it to create a new instance.

Comment: So you mean this will not work within a VPC with `10.0.0.0/16`?

Answer (score -1):

EC2 instances are used as a backend for kubernetes in the AWS cloud.
You can always run necessary number of instances manually and deploy any service above.

The following article describes how to launch your EC2 instance:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/getting-started-launch-instance.html

By the way, Amazon already provides a managed service similar to kubernetes based on docker. I will suggest you to consider using it. 
More information here:
https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/details/